# Graphical application, kiosk mode: fullscreen?

Tags: x11

I installed a debian system which automatically starts a graphical application (clementine) when logging in as a certain user. The command run at login is `/usr/bin/startx /usr/bin/clementine`, which works fine. However, the application is not filling the complete screen, i.e., there are black bars on the right and bottom. Has anybody an idea how to start the application full-screen? There is no command line option for the program (like `--fullscreen`). I also don't want to install a window manager since the system is supposed to run as kiosk mode.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not what you ask but a workaround.
Since Clementine don't look to respond to `-geometry` option nor similar, you can use xdotool to maximize the window.

I think you will need to change the way to run clementine from `startx` arguments to a entry in a `.xinitrc` file in the user home directory but after a call to `xdotool` in the same file. Make a `.xinitrc` file in the user home directory with this content.

```
/usr/bin/xdotool search "Clementine" -sync windowsize 100% 100%
/usr/bin/clementine
```

From now on when you run `startx`, it will load `.xinitrc` and run those commands.
`xdotool` will search a window called Clementine, `search "Clementine"` , in the background, `-sync`.
So with `xdotool` waiting for a window called Clementine, you call `/usr/bin/clementine`.
Now when `xdotool` found the window immediately will change its size to fullscreen, `windowsize 100% 100%`.

`xdotool` utility is included in xdotool Debian package.

If above example reduce clementine's windows to 100x100, that is because your `xdotool` version doesn't support percentages.

xdotool 2.20100818.* and above support percentages in 'windowsize'. So if you are below this still can get the root window resolution, to hardcode it, by sending the `xwininfo -root` and checking the `-geometry` line (last one).

i.e. if you get a `-geometry 1024x768+0+0` line, the resulting .xinitrc would be:

```
/usr/bin/xdotool search "Clementine" -sync windowsize 1024 768
/usr/bin/clementine
```

Comment: Didn't know about that tool. I'll have a look at it. Thanks!