# Running X Appplication Without Desktop Environment in full screen

Tags: kiosk

I'm tryng to configure a Linux to work as a kiosk running google-earth only and
I'm just following a guide about how to run google-earth Without Desktop Environment that it would be perfect for me:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-x-applications-without-a-desktop-or-a-wm

Basically if i boot in `multi-user.target` running from a Terminal this command:

```
xinit google-earth-pro $* -- :0 vt$XDG_VTNR
```

I'm able to open google-earth-pro but it will not run in full screen, and the actual window seems to be no resizable, even pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>.

In this workstation there is a NVIDIA Card but the driver are't still installed it could be this the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphical application, kiosk mode: fullscreen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237763/graphical-application-kiosk-mode-fullscreen)

Comment: How about using a tiling window manager as your X11 session? Then most new windows from any app will be full screen.

Comment: forget about using google earth / firefox / chrome without a window manager. they won't work reliably, *even* if some quick testing seem satisfactory (they will show empty or unclosable tooltips, drop-down lists wont drop down, text fields won't focus, etc). In particular, in X11, it's the wm which should be resizing top windows, and F11 is implemented by sending a message to the window manager (`_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN`).

Comment: @user313992 So what _is_ the best setup for this use case?