# Runnig python window app on linux (Fedora) without gdm

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, python, gdm

I have a small project, the project is running python (windows application) as below.On linux Fedora without using gdm,Gdm must be disabled. Any Idea please?
What library I have to download ?

```
# importing tkinter for gui
import tkinter as tk
 
# creating window
window = tk.Tk()
 
# setting attribute
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.title("Geeks For Geeks")
 
# creating text label to display on window screen
label = tk.Label(window, text="Hello Tkinter!")
label.pack()
 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load your own GUI app without the rest of the GUI in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472781/how-to-load-your-own-gui-app-without-the-rest-of-the-gui-in-linux)

Comment: Or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237763/graphical-application-kiosk-mode-fullscreen)?

Comment: I will try it ,Thanks